# Laravel - retrieving a model through another model's builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code:

```
$stores = $this->user->markets()->stores();
```

Which gives the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::stores()
```

I've read about using `with()`:

```
$stores = $this->user->markets()->with('stores');
```

This works, but it is retrieving `markets` with `stores` in each market. How do I get a builder object of `stores` that belong to the user's `markets`?

User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function markets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Market');
    }
}
```

Market model:

```
class Market extends Eloquent {
    public function stores()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Store');
    }
}
```

Comment: $this->user->load('markets.stores');

Comment: @SofianeSadi this is grabbing a user model. I would like to grab a collection of stores - or better yet, builder that will grab stores.

Comment: $stores = Market::where('user_id',$this->user->id)->with('stores')->get();   ,this will give a collection of specific user markets and the stores for each ( if this dosent help, can you please provide more explaination on what you want?

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja I only want a collection of stores. No markets.

Comment: ah so you want to retrieve all stores of a user(or all users) without the market while you dont have a direct relation between them?

Comment: you can loop that and add the  $stores ->store to a collection i think

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Would hasManyThrough work for this application? It seems like looping through markets and executing a bunch of SQL queries to get the stores would be taxing.

Comment: you are supposed to loop and get data from the eagerly loaded data not to perform all those querys